# How to handle NonInteractive mode notice thrown as an exception

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I am invoking an exe program by "&" in Powershell; Howerver, "Windows PowerShell is in NonInteractive mode. Read and Prompt functionality is not available." is thrown as an exception though the exe completed successfully. I was wondering whether there is a good way to handle this beside leaving a blank catch block because the exe might still throw other exceptions.

Comment: Either your executable or your PowerShell script(?) tries to interact with the user, but you started PowerShell in non-interactive mode. You can't have both.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Thanks for your commetn, it turned out that it was not the exe problem, I was using "Remove-Item"  and it caused the problem.